# Unsupported scheme error when using "ls" command on a Java package

Tags: java, rascal

I am working on a function that gives a list of code volume per package in for a Java M3. This function looks like this:

```
public list[int] calculateSizePerComponent(M3 model){
    set[loc] packages = packages(model);
    list[int] componentSizes = [];
    for(package <- packages){
        list[loc] classFiles = [x | x <- package.ls, endsWith(x.file, ".java")];
        if(size(classFiles)>0){
            int sourceSize = 0;
            for(classFile <- classFiles){
                sourceSize+=getLinesOfCode(classFile).linesOfCode;
            }
            componentSizes += sourceSize;
        }
    }
    return componentSizes;
}
```

I use the following function to calculate the amount of lines of code (volume) in a Java compilation unit (which works for other examples):

```
public tuple[int linesOfCode,int blankLines,int commentLines] getLinesOfCode(loc location) {
    int linesOfCode = 0;
    int blankLines = 0;
    int commentLines = 0;
    bool incomment = false; 

    srcLines = readFileLines(location);     
    for (line <- srcLines) {
        switch(line){
            case /^\s*\/\/\s*\w*/: commentLines += 1; // Line preceded by '//'
            case /((\s*\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/)+[\s\w]+(\/\/[\s\w]+$)*)+/: linesOfCode += 1; // Line containing Java code containing any amount of comments. Example: code /**comment*/ code /**comment*/ code
            case /^\s*\/\*?[\w\s\?\@]*\*\/$/: commentLines += 1; // Line containing single line comment: /*comment*/
            case /\s*\/\*[\w\s]*\*\/[\s\w]+/: linesOfCode += 1; // Line containing a comment, but also code. Example: /**comment*/ code
            case /^[\s\w]*\*\/\s*\w+[\s\w]*/: {incomment = false; linesOfCode += 1;} // Line closing a multi-line comment, but also containing code. Example: comment*/ code
            case /^\s*\/\*\*?[^\*\/]*$/: {incomment = true; commentLines += 1;} // Line opening a multi-line comment, Example: /**comment
            case /\s*\*\/\s*$/: {commentLines += 1; incomment = false;} // Line closing a multi-line comment, Example: comment*/
            case /^\s*$/: blankLines += 1; // Blank line
            default: if (incomment) commentLines += 1; else linesOfCode += 1;
        }
    }
    return <linesOfCode,blankLines,commentLines>;
}
```

However, `package.ls` seems to return results that have a wrong scheme. Due to this, I get the following error at the `readFileLines` call:

```
|std:///IO.rsc|(14565,775,<583,0>,<603,43>): IO("Unsupported scheme java+package")
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///IO.rsc|(14565,775,<583,0>,<603,43>))
        at readFileLines(|project://Software_Evolution/src/metrics/volume.rsc|(1911,8,<49,26>,<49,34>))
        at calculateSizePerComponent(|project://Software_Evolution/src/metrics/componentsize.rsc|(1996,38,<64,16>,<64,54>))
        at getComponentSize(|project://Software_Evolution/src/metrics/componentsize.rsc|(267,1112,<15,0>,<42,1>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,30,<1,0>,<1,30>))
```

When I println the location, I get the following:

```
|java+package:///smallsql/database/language/Language.java|
```

This is incorrect, because this is a java compilationunit and not a package. How do I get the lines of code in this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step analysis:

- `package.ls` works because first the logical URI is resolved by the registry "name server" to an actual physical folder on disk. If that is indeed a directory then `.ls` has the right semantics and you get back a list of files in that folder.
- the loc `|java+package:///smallsql/database/language/Language.java|` actually points to a file and not even a compilationUnit.
- something unintended is going on with the construction of the child locations, it takes the old logical location of the folder and simply concatenates the name of the child file "Language.java", but that does not make sense.
- I fixed this bug in the current master, and an unstable release is forthcoming in a few minutes
- but you can also work around this by first resolving the package location to a physical location: `resolve(package).ls` should do much better.

PS: the regular expressions are rather error prone, and you might have to deal with a lot of corner cases. I'd use a real parser generated from a syntax definition for Java, or use the syntax trees which already produced by M3 via the Eclipse compiler to compute the SLOC.

Comment: oops. I reverted the bugfix because some downstream regression tests failed on the CI. have to take some time to look into that; in the meantime please use the workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. Rascal is awesome :-).

Comment: Concerning this: `I'd use a real parser generated from a syntax definition for Java, or use the syntax trees which already produced by M3 via the Eclipse compiler to compute the SLOC.`, can you point me to some sources on how to derive the SLOC without deriving the actual source lines in the source files? I indeed have some issues with my regexes.

Comment: I would look at the definition of the m3::AST.rsc for Java in the library, each node has a field with its source position. You know how many lines the entire method has and which lines each statement and expression covers. Etc. Can't do your homework but that gives a hint. Also in Lang::standard are example syntax definitions for comments and whitespace, you could make an "island parser" with those. Or finally you might extend the Java 4 parser in Lang::Java to cover your dialect and count the whitespsce and comments on those trees. Many options, that is also Rascal. Pick what you like best

Answer (score 2):

The Rascal function `resolveLocation` ended up solving the problem. So instead of `package.ls`, I had to use `resolveLocation(package).ls`.